# Question about combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

On a circle with perimeter 24 there are 24 equally spaced points, marked 1 to 24. In how many ways can we choose 8 out of these 24 points so that the lengths of the minor arc joining any two of the chosen points is not equal to 3 or 8?

After hours of calculations, I get the answer of 2880. I don't know is the answer right, but can someone help me with the solution which I can't figure out how to elaborate. That will be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I was not able to understand the part *the lengths of the minor are joining...* Should that be *segments*?

Comment: *How* did you get the answer $2880$?  No one cares what answer you got but everyone cares *how* you got it. .... You must show work and/or thought.  Saying I think the answer is such and such is not work nor is it thought.

Comment: @user376343, that confused me too, until I realized that "*are*" should be "*arc*".  And of course that typo is with the most important word in the entire question.

Comment: By exhaustive numeration (a short Python program), the answer is $258$.